# Rails - application design for 2 user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am writing ruby on rails app, that will have 2 different types of users (let's say sellers and buyers). I was thinking about using single table inheritance, but ultimately I decided to crate 2 separate models (I believe it's better solution in my case).

The problem is when I try to create private message model (both sellers and buyers can contact each other). Typically I would just generate model called message with 3 fields (from_user_id to_user_id and content). This will not work in my case, because there might be 2 users with the same id (1 seller and 1 buyer).

I was thinking about using e-mail to identify sender and receiver, but e-mail is not my primary key, so I guess I won't be able to use it a foreign key in message model. Oh - btw, what is the best way to make sure that e-mails are unique in both sellers and buyers tables (in other words user can't join as a seller and buyer from one email)

Any ideas how I can elegantly solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a polymorphic association. What this allows you to do is have a model that can belong to multiple other models through the same relationship by specifying the ID as well as the Class of the other object. For example, if buyer ID 3 sends a message to seller ID 5, your message table will end up with a row like:

```
sender_id = 3
sender_type = Buyer
receiver_id = 5
receiver_type = Seller
```

To accomplish this in active record, your models will look like the following:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :receiver, :polymorphic => true
end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :as => :sender
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :as => :receiver
end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :as => :sender
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :as => :receiver
end
```

Comment: OK - this seems to be the perfect solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you decided to not have a single User model? Considered all the issues caused by having these users in two separated tables I would have a User model and extend this model to have a Buyer model and a Seller model.

I think a buyer or a seller is still a user of your application, this resolves the problem of the message from a user to another too.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Remember to add a "type" column in the users table
end

class Seller < User
end

class Buyer < User
end
```

The messages are now between users, no matter which kind of user.

Comment: There are 3 reasons why I don't want to use single table inheritance:
1) I don't want to have a lot of columns in my user table (I would have to store fileds for both seller and buyer in one table)
2) I don't want to have a lot of null values in my database
3) Keeping sellers and buyers separated will help to improve performace speed (I am not planning any queries on joined tables)

Comment: 1/2) I don't know why it's so hidden but some time ago I discovered this [1], it's a simple way to implement STI. (I'm not saying it's right to use it, but it's simple and it make sense to me)

3) I don't think it should reduce so much your application speed

[1]: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance

Comment: Queries will be faster, because there will only be half of rows in each table :)

Comment: I would not be so sure, some time ago I removed the vast mayority of rows in a tables with thousands of rows and measured the queries times thinking it would be significantly faster...the queries were run at the same speed. DBMS usually add indices on your primary keys so I guess the join between a users and a admins table should be very fast.